# childWindow Full Screen Event tweak the Parent to also FullSCreen Mode

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a ChildWindow which contains a ExpressionMediaPlayer inside it. When I click on the ChildWindow Media Player Full screen button it swiches the whole application to FullScreen Mode.

Is there a way to avoid  it. I am not quite sure if this scenario is going to fall under SL security restrictions.

When I drag the ChildWindow(the position of ChildWindow changes)  and click on the fullscreen 
now the ChildWindow also changes it's position.

For example if I have dragged the ChildWindow 50px from Top and pressed the Full Screen button of of mediaPlayer (it contains) the Child Window also appears 50 pixels below the Screen Top.
But I want My ChildWindow to be FullScreen without having any Gap from LEFT,TOP,RIGHT or below.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Subhen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight only uses one of its two windows.  The first is the normal window embedded in the Host application such as IE (or in windowless mode it co-operates with the host to draw directly on one of the host's windows in a give rectangle).  The other window is a Fullscreen one.

When in full screen mode it moves all its rendering of its stack of content to the full screen window.  You can't get Silverlight to render only some controls on the Fullscreen window, its an all or nothing proposition.

Creating a "fullscreenable" ChildWindow would be an interesting exercise.  Probably a new templated control based on Childwindow with a new "Fullscreen" visual state (in a new state group) that hides the chrome and causes the content grid to stretch with Auto Width and Height.